# How can i display values in session object in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having problems with debugging issues. I'm trying to print on a .html.erb file the value of a variable stored in session hash. I'm using a debug screen for session parameters that confirms me that all variables are present but when browser starts to render html code, i cannot see the value i need.

In controller class i have:

```
@var = session[:var]
```

and in html.erb file

```
<%= @var %>
```

I'm using this code for the debug screen:

```
<%# in application.html.erb %>
<%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
```

where I'm wrong?

Comment: can you tell us more about your "debug screen." what tool / code are you using for your debug screen? are you checking the variables when they're in the controller or the view? are you checking the value of session[:var] or @var or both?

Comment: I'm using this code for debug screen, i put this line in the application.html.erb:
<%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
i'm checking the value of @var, because the debug screen says this:
"session: !ruby/hash-with-ivars:ActionController::Parameters
    elements:
      var: '5'
    ivars:
      :@permitted: false"
so i thought that everything's fine in session[:var].

Comment: i'd advise to add a debugger to the controller method -- pry works good. https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails you would just have `biding.pry` after your `@var = session[:var]`. Otherwise provide more code on your controller actions + view.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your debug code:

```
<%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
```

It looks like you're checking the `params` object and not the `session` object. `params` is an object which holds GET and POST data for the current request. `session`, however, uses cookies to hold data over multiple requests.

If this data is something you only need for this particular page, you should just use params directly:

```
@var = params[:var]
```

If you actually do want to save this data in the user's session, you'll need to do that before you can access it:

```
# session[:var] will be available in future requests,
# long after params[:var] and @var have been cleared.
session[:var] = params[:var]
@var = session[:var]
```